# How to control quality of light baking in 3DS Max?

Tags: 3ds-max, shadows, lighting-effects

Our team has been struggling to figure why a shadow/light is rendered with high quality and something rendered in low quality (pixalite).

Example of good light map (shadow of sofa on the wall and floor)

[image: High quality shadow of sofa]

Example of bad light map (shadow on ceiling is completely pixalite)

[image: Low quality shadow]

We are using a 3D party plugin (flare3d exporter) which accepts only texture quality parameters in the farm of min and max values. I guess this is is using for auto-mapping parameters. `32 - 1024` is the default values. If we put the default, most of the lighting comes bad if we give max `1024-1024` range not only the rendering time is longer but the model size also increases.

**We were not sure how many lights maps m3ds max will create and what is its consideration for determining the quality (`32px x 32px` - `1024px x 1024px`) of light map**

After lot of trail & errors we came to a wage opinion that the number of light maps and its dimensions are equal to the numbre of uv maps. But again we are not sure which one would create a low quality light map and for which one it creates a high quality texture.

Can some one help me understand how it works?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 3D modeling/design questions are now off-topic for this site.  There is a [petition for a 3D site here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-graphics)